# how to take data from a jQuery function?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-select2

I have the following script to search for a product in a select2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#productSelect").select2({
    placeholder: 'Seleccione un Producto',
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
      url: 'PrdSearch.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 50,
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results: data
        };
      },
      cache: true
    }
  });

});
```

and the PrdSearch.php file that does the search

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");
if (empty($_GET['q'])) exit ;
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $q = stripslashes($q);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " .$database_table_prefix."products" . " WHERE prd_name like '%$q%' or prd_code like '%$q%' ORDER BY prd_name LIMIT 20";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->rowCount();
$result = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $result [] = ['id'=>$row['prd_id'], 'text'=>$row['prd_name']];
}
echo json_encode($result);?>
```

It works well and brings the `prd_id` and `prd_name` of a single product in the values of `id` and `text` respectively, the `name` is placed as a `value` in the `<select>` correctly.

I tried to bring more product data such as `code` and `price` among others by adding the `keys` and the `values` in the array `$result`, I do not get any error but I do not know how to recover that additional data from the array, I know that the value of `"text"` is remains in the `<select>` but the other fields how I recover them?

The other thing is, if I already have the fields how I assign the values to the input of the form?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX function you can decode the json and access any data you want. Try this.

```
ajax: {
      url: 'PrdSearch.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 50,
      processResults: function (data) {
        var d = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert(d.price);
        return {
          results: data
        };
      },
      cache: true
    }
```

This way you can access any data from your encoded json file. Hope it helps.
To assign the values to the form you just have to use the following code.

```
$("#input_id").val(d.price); //it will assign the product price to the input with id "input_id"
```

Comment: The part of taking the results is perfect, but where should I put the $ ("# input_id"). Val (d.price) ;? if I put it before the return it only takes the last data of the query. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Can you please show your result? What are you getting in d?

Comment: This is correct can you please tell me what problem are you facing again? @JuanCarlos

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping out your AJAX call with the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'PrdSearch.php',
  dataType: 'POST',
  success: function (data) {
    processResults(data); // assume this fuction is declared elsewhere now
  } else {
    // ajax failed msg
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the `select2` data is stored in`e.params.data` so the script is like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

      $('#productSelect').on("select2:select", function (e) {
        $("#inv_code").val(e.params.data.code);
        $("#inv_price").val(e.params.data.price);
       });


      $("#productSelect").select2({
        placeholder: 'Seleccione un Producto',
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        ajax: {
          url: 'PrdSearch.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          delay: 50,
          processResults: function (data) {
            return {
              results: data
            };
          },
          cache: true
        }
      });

    });
```

thanks for your contributions